# Import Excel worksheet into SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I have an SISS package that imports from Excel into SQL 2005. The name of the worksheet changes baseed on the date the file was created, so a worksheet name would be 20120911.

I want to standardize the worksheet name by automatically changing it.

Is this possible? I've done a lot of searching but haven't found a solution. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure your connection (ExcelFilePath property) with an [SSIS expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141214%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). Remember to set the "DelayValidation" of your dataflow task and connection manager to "true" so SSIS doesn't throw unwanted exceptions.

[Here](http://bidn.com/blogs/kylewalker/ssis/997/setting-up-an-ssis-package-with-a-dymanic-excel-source) is a great example of how to do it.